# Getting a value from a url

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get QueryString values with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)

Hey guys,

I got a question if i have a  tag that looks like this:

```
<a href="?page=cart&amp;action=order&amp;ISBN={$boek.ISBN}">Add to basket</a>
```

What would be the best way to select the value of ISBN in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with plain JS.

see: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)

Other answers in the link above point to jQuery solutions and plugins too.

Comment: Flag this question as a duplicate then, don't post a link to *another* answer to the same question.

Comment: @Nick: Is there a list of guidelines such as these somewhere? How do you expect new users to understand what the 'right' thing to do is?

Comment: If it's a duplicate, close it.  Clicking your rep at the top takes you to a list of what your rep level entitles you to do with a description of each, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions

Comment: That helps mate! First time I'm reading that. Part of the reason being my custom stylish userstyle that hides 'junk' in the side panel. Now fixed. Voted to close this now.

Answer (score 0):

By using a plugin, like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/url_parser